# extract column information from a single df and input to multiple dfs where identifier needs remapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I need to append the row data from a column in df1 into separate dfs.
The row value from column 'i1' in df1 should correspond to the name of the dataframe that it needs appending too and there is a common id column across dataframes.

However - the i1 name and the name of the tables are different. I have created a dictionary below so you can see what i mean.

```
d_map = {'ab1':'c30_sab1',
         'cd2':'kjm_1cd2'}
```

example data and the expected output is shown below is shown with df1. Any pointers would be great. thanks so much

**df1**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'i1': ['ab1','cd2','ab1','cd2','ab1'], 'i2': ['10:25','10:27','11:51','12:01','13:18']})
```

**tables that need appending with i2 column from df1 depending on id and i1 match**

```
c30_sab = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3]})
kjm_1cd = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2]})
```

**expected output**

```
e_ab1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'i2': ['10:25','11:51','13:18']})
e_cd2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2], 'i2': ['10:27','12:01']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it (assuming you accept repetitions when the `df` ids are duplicated):

```
df_ab1 = df[df['i1'] == 'ab1']  # select only the values for 'ab1' df
df_cd2 = df[df['i1'] == 'cd2']  # select only the values for 'cd2' df

e_ab_1 = ab1.merge(df_ab1[['id', 'i2']], on='id')
e_cd_2 = cd2.merge(df_cd2[['id', 'i2']], on='id')
```

Comment: thanks @sophros. so i just edited the question as in some cases, the i1 value does not match the table name and needs remapping in order to append properly do you perhaps have any suggestions there? thanks again!!

Comment: I see. Didn't see it at first. But now updated the answer to do what you need.